# List of directories off of the root of VOB in cleartool

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

If I am in a vob (pwd command displays the correct vob) and `lsvob <VOB_NAME>` returns some info about the vob, how can I get a list of all the directories from the root?  The `setview` command has also been run.

When I do `ls`, I get:

```
Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd /vobs/myvob
cleartool ls
# or 
cleartool find . -type d -print
```

The first one lists all elements within the view.
The other one lists all the directories.

---

The [OP foampile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312080/foampile) mentions:

> `cleartool mount /vob/<MY_VOB>`
>   i tried that but got:

```
Mounting MVFS filesystem /vob/<MY_VOB>.... mount: Device busy
```

The IBM page "[mount: Device busy](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21150408)" can help.

As long as:

```
ct startview myDynamicView
ct setview myDynamicView
ct mount /vobs/MyVob
cd /vobs/MyVob
ct pwv
```

gives:

```
Working directory view: ** NONE ** 
Set view: <MY_VIEW_ID>
```

That is not good, and would point to a faulty config spec, as the IBM technote "
[Accessing a ClearCase VOB's root folder yields "`No such file or directory`"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21616739)" illustrates.

Comment: I get: `Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "."`

Comment: when i do `pwd`, i get the proper vob -- but i do not know how to navigate further because i can't get a directory listing

Comment: @foa that would be because of your config spec : copy the result of cleartool catcs. Make sure also that the Vob is mounted.

Comment: `catcs` does not return any useful information.  what do you mean by `Vob is mounted`?

Comment: @foampile if '`cleartool catcs`' doesn't return anything, that means you aren't in a ClearCase view, which explains the error message. Check, in `/vobs/myVob`, the result of `cleartool pwv`: it must return the name of the current view. If not, you must try again the `cleartool setview myView`, and also `cleartool startview myView` (obviously, replace `myVob` or `myView` by your actual vob or view name).

Comment: @foampile by 'mounted', I mean type `cleartool mount /vobs/MyVob` (if already mounted, it won't do anything). With dynamic views, you need to mount vobs to access their content.

Comment: `cleartool catcs` does return some data but i don't know how to read it.  unfortunately, the contents are company property and i don't want to post it -- i hope you understand

Comment: @foampile ok, what about `cleartool pwv` (to check that you are actually in a view)?

Comment: that returns good value:  `Working directory view: ** NONE ** Set view: <MY_VIEW_ID>`

Comment: @foampile `Working directory view: ** NONE **`: that is your issue right there: see the examples of http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_pwv.htm : the working directory should be the view name.

Comment: @foampile so it is back to the config spec, as in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21616739 for instance, which looks like your case.

Comment: so, are you saying if i do `mount /vob/<MY_VOB>`, the working dir should be set?  i tried that but got: `Mounting MVFS filesystem /vob/<MY_VOB>.... mount: Device busy`

Comment: @foampile not a good sign. But even if the mount was successful, you still need to execute those `cleartool` commands (like `pvw`) in `/vobs/MyVob`, assuming you did start and set the view. On that specific error message, see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21150408 .

Comment: I will try to talk to CC admins here at the company ...  they are not always easy to reach.  will keep you posted.  thanks @VonC

Comment: @foampile ok, I have included in the answer the relevant links and error messages for more visibility.