# Running multiple commands in a single cleartool session from a script?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

#### Question

The [cleartool documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/cleartool.htm) mentions a "Single command mode" and an "Interactive mode".  Single command mode lets you run a single command non-interactively.  Interactive mode lets you run multiple commands within an interactive session?

I need to run multiple commands from a script using the same session.  More specifically, I need to run a `cd` command to switch to a view directory so I can run `find -avobs`.  I can't use the single command mode, because the working directory is lost between each invocation of `cleartool`.

Is it possible to write a script to interact using using the interactive mode, or otherwise run multiple commands in the same session from a script?

---

Note - I have considered running `cd` from within the batch script, instead of from within cleartool.  However, I want to use the syntax `cd \\view\<view-tag>`, but when I try to run this from cmd.exe, I get an error:

> CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.

And even if I do find a way to solve this without multiple commands in a single session, I'm still interested in whether it is possible in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cd in a bash script with `cleartool` command (Single command mode).

In Windows, a dynamic view would be accessed with

```
cd m:\MyDynamicView
```

After that, any cleartool command would be executed in the context of that directory (dynamic view)

Same for a snapshot view.

```
cd c:\path\to\root\snapshotview
```

The UNC path is reserved for the view *storage* (which must be accessible for any client).
It is not for the view root directory.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927206/cleartool-question/2927385#2927385) as an example of `cleartool` commands used after a `cd`: they can be used in a script without problem.

Note that you have to start the view first (if it is a dynamic view): see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794088/list-of-directories-off-of-the-root-of-vob-in-cleartool/13794249#13794249) to see a concrete example.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, can't the user choose a drive letter other than `M:`?  Is there an easy way to determine the drive letter being used?  I'm wondering if instead of having the user to provide the name of a view, I should have them provide a filesystem path to a view instead.

Comment: @KevinK for dynamic views, this is always `M:\`, so the view name is enough. No need for the complete filesystem path. You can choose another driver in the ClearCase settings: see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21150832.

Comment: @KevinK Note that the dynamic view drive letter is stored in the Windows Registry at "`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Mvfs\Parameters\drive`". See for instance http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/archives/cciug/hypermail/0210/0592.html